# What are some of the ways to store data using Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic?

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, local-storage, ionic-framework

So as the title suggests. Just wanted to know some ways to store various data on cordova apps. Not sure how this works since local storage is a browser thing, but does this work when applied to native apps on phones? can you use something like SQLite for large amounts of information and models?

Comment: I'd start by looking at the [storage options listed in the Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:  After some more research, the best solution to use in a PhoneGap environment would be [angular-localforage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage)

https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage

This angular service takes advantage of [Mozilla LocalForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) which will attempt to use the most robust solution to save your data, but then will fall back on simpler, more compatible options.

Answer (score 3):

[localForage](http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/), more simplified offline storage from Mozilla

http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/

Use this with any js library and store things like

- Array
- ArrayBuffer
- Blob
- Float32Array
- Float64Array
- Int8Array
- Int16Array
- Int32Array
- Number
- Object
- Uint8Array
- Uint8ClampedArray
- Uint16Array
- Uint32Array
- String

Comment: +1 for localForage. Will use the best available storage in the device (IndexedDB, WebSQL) or fall back to LocalStorage.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning localForage, I will definitely look into using this in the future. For now I think the cordova SQLite plugin matches my needs.